# How to get complete info on Machine learning algorithms in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server-2016

I am using SQL Server 2016, I got some basic knowledge on linear model (rxLinMod),
logistic regression, Decision Tree, random forest but failed to get info on svm, naiveBayees etc....

Where can I get complete info on the machine learning algorithms in SQL Server 2016?

Answer (score 0):

So SQL Server R Services consists of the various propitiatory RevoScaleR algorithms, which you can read about in the MS docs. Then it also consists of whatever algorithms that ships with the "normal" CRAN R. In addition you can add packages with all sorts of "weird and wonderful" algorithms from CRAN. For these, you need to find the documentation yourself from various places.